# Page header - Upper and lower case

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, header-footer, capitalization

First of all: this is the first time that I use LaTeX.

I have these commands that create my header:

```
\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrpage2}    
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\clearscrheadfoot %clear everything
\ohead[\rightmark ~$\vert$ \pagemark]{\rightmark ~$\vert$ \pagemark} %define header for beginning of chapter and "normal" pages
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\ #1}} %??
\setheadsepline{1pt} %set size of sep-line
```

Everything works as intended, except: On the pages containing the bibliography or the ToC, the name of the chapter is in upper case letters, and elsewhere it is as in the chapter headline.

How can I change that so that the chapter title is not formatted to upper case in the ToC and bibliography?

PS: It would be great if you also could explain the second last line. I understand what it does, but I don't know where `\chaptermark` is used and thus why it affects the header...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem description points to a "feature" in the LaTeX standard classes like `book` and `report`: Headers for standard chapters are formatted using `\chaptermark` which in turn calls the `\MakeUppercase` macro which does exactly what it name suggests. Your redefinition of `\chaptermark` removes `\MakeUppercase` for standard chapters. However, `\MakeUppercase` is hard-coded into the header of the ToC and the bibliography. Solution: Use the `nouppercase` option of `scrpage2` which disables `\MakeUpperCase` in the header.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline,nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\clearscrheadfoot %clear everything
\ohead[\rightmark ~$\vert$ \pagemark]{\rightmark ~$\vert$ \pagemark} %define header for beginning of chapter and "normal" pages
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\ #1}} %??
\setheadsepline{1pt} %set size of sep-line

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

\lipsum[1-12]

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}

\chapter{bar}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```