# How to modify the headers of this book to lower case?

Tags: header-footer

In the following standard `\documentclass{book}` all headers are in upper case.

How can I modify the code below to make lower case headers?

The even pages show the chapter number and name, and the odd pages show the section number and name. The first page of a chapter has no header, only the page number in the footer. The other pages show the page numbers on the headers: odd pages on the right and even pages on the left, as shown.

[image]

[image]

It was created with

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Standard \LaTeX{} Book}
\author{The Author}
\date{The Date}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{Test Section Two}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{Test Section Three}
\lipsum[1-6]

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{Test Section Two}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Remark: the question [Page header - Upper and lower case](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51598/1862)  is not sufficiently similar to this one to help me to find a possible solution by my own.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is in my opinion the worse design error in the `book` class. Not because of the uppercase default (which I consider bad anyway), but because there's no way to easily change it. And the `\MakeUppercase` is hardwired in the macros.

You can change the behavior by loading the `fancyhdr` package, and adding

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

to your preamble. You can also load `\usepackage{emptypage}` to remove headers and footers with the empty pages produced by `\cleardoublepage`.

The rule below headers is produced by default, so if you want it, comment out the `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` line.

Or using a class that provides for changing the default, for instance `memoir` or `scrbook`.

Comment: Many thanks! This solves my problem too and replies to the additional question on how to add a headrule.

Comment: Is it possible to change the header from italic to normal, by adding some code?

Comment: @AméricoTavares Just use `\normalfont` instead of `\itshape`.

Answer (score 9):

The [`regexpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch) package can help you to remove the `\MakeUppercase` macros from `\tableofcontents` and the `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` macros:

```
\usepackage{regexpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch
\makeatletter
% \*patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\xpatchcmd{\chaptermark}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}%
\xpatchcmd{\sectionmark}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}%
\xpatchcmd*{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}%
\makeatother
```

`\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` adds `\MakeUppercase` to all headings supplied, which is removed by the first two `\xpatchcmd` commands. `\tableofcontents` sets its own heading in `\MakeUppercase`, and is therefore not handled by `\chaptermark` - the reason for this is that it is actually a `\chapter*` and requires special attention. `\xpatchcmd*` does a search-and-replace-all on `\MakeUppercase`.

Comment: There are other places where the dreadful `\MakeUppercase` appears; a real case of bad design, IMO. :-(

Comment: Many thanks! This solves my problem. To add a *headrule* does one need to define headers and footers by means of `\fancyhf`?

Comment: @AméricoTavares: Yes, and I see that egreg already suggested a [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) solution.

Comment: @AméricoTavares Well, one _does not need_ to use `\fancyhf`, but it is a complicated task, and why do it again if someone else has prepared a nice package for you to use? :)

Comment: @tohecz Of course I can/should use `\fancyhf` for adding a rule.

Comment: Just a naive question: what if one does `\let\MakeUppercase=\relax` ? Does this have large and painful implications ?

Comment: @VincentFourmond  Thank you, sir. The side-effects of the `\let` command, if any, can be minimized by limiting its scope (with braces) and/or delaying it until it is needed. In my case, because I had already redefined `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark`, it was enough to put the `\let\MakeUppercase=\relax` command before `\tableofcontents` (within braces) and at the beginning of the backmatter. That avoids the need for any packages (which, for all I know, may have their own side-effects).